# unknown problem upgrading Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade

I started the upgrading process but it stops here

[image: myscreen]

I don't know what can I do. Thanks for help

PD: Sorry for the bad picture

Comment: Also is important to say that the process of the upgrading doesn't change in 1 hour. It stops and still there .

Comment: Did you type on the terminal to answer the prompt for Unttended-upgrades?   If you press ENTER it should proceed with the default action.

Comment: yes James,I press ENTER, also "Y", "N", "no", "yes" and it don't do nothing. Do you recommend to kill the process (with "Crl + C") and the restart and see what happen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The system is locked up**

This is verified by hour without a terminal update and no hard disk activity.  You are monitoring the terminal.

There's nothing you can do except recycle the system.

Perform the reboot in this order, to have the safest shutdown:

1. First hit `ctrl+alt+del` and follow the prompts.
2. If that fails, tap the power switch and follow the safe shutdown prompts.
3. If that fails, hold the power switch pressed until the system shuts down.

I have experienced similar occasions where the upgrade didn't continue.  Restarting the system, I was able to pickup where it left off by cycling thought these commands until it was fully upgraded:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

After cycling a few time I had a fully upgraded system, eventually with no errors.